# How do I efficiently select unique row/record data from 2 mysql tables and return one merged result, ordered by timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Stack:

I'm trying to turn my website's user profile into more of a feed style page. Currently the profile shows some user stats at the top, then the last 10 comments a user submitted (ordered by timestamp descending), then the last 10 posts they have submitted.

What I want to do instead, is have the last 20 "actions" (either comment or post submission) listed in order of the timestamp (so the comments and submissions will be merged together in the list instead of having 2 seperate lists). You know, like a "feed."

The issue is that the comments are pulled from a comments table, and the submissions are pulled from a "submissions" table.

I've solved it in a pretty inefficient way by using a union query to select "comment_id/submission_id", "field the identifies record as a comment or a submission", "timestamp" from both tables.

This gives me a result that tells my the entity id, as well as defines the entity as a comment or a post, by which I can then shoot off another query in a while mysql_fetch_array statement to get the full comment or submission data.

This just seems really dirty to me, since I'm basically querying the tables, finding the rows/records that I need (but ignoring the actual data I need since the different table's columns don't match up as I believe to be necessary for a union query), then going back for the data I ignored the first time with individual queries in a while statement...

Is there a better way to do this that I don't know of?

Additional notes:

---

Example sql I'm currently using to build the initial result I spoke of above:

```
select comment_id, datatype, timestamp from comments where userid=3
union all
select content_id, datatype, timestamp from submissions where userid=3
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Returns a result like this:

```
commentid  datatype      timestamp 
5201       post          2012-03-27 20:30:40
43761      comment       2012-03-26 21:00:19
43759      comment       2012-03-26 20:59:47
5033       post          2012-03-26 20:57:36
43755      comment       2012-03-26 20:54:57
43745      comment       2012-03-26 16:32:24
```

Pseudocode I can then use to print out the information onto the profile page:

while ($content_array = mysql_fetch_array($abovequery)){

Individual select query fetching the full row by from either comment table or submission table by id depending on $content_array['datatype'];

echo out relevant data from individual select query onto profile screen in a pretty way;

}

Surely this can be done better?

Comment: What are the table structures? Why are you running individual queries to retrieve full record instead of returning the full record in the UNION query?

Comment: @nnichols I was under the impression Union queries needed to have the exact same number of columns selected from both tables, and they had to be the same data type. I need a pretty distinct set of fields returned from each table respectively. What do you think of supernoobs join/distinct solution below regarding performance?

Comment: Your impression is correct. But there are still ways of doing this that are better than running another query for each row returned. Unless you post the table structures and current queries we cannot possibly help you. I don't think SuperNoob was suggesting a solution, more that you should search.

Comment: @nnichols Well I believe he was hinting at doing the query using select distinct in a join rather than using a union. That's what I was referring to. I'm going to update post with relevant structure info now, thanks.

Comment: @nnichols Upon further review, I don't believe any type of join will solve my issue and I am stuck with a union. The question is, can I put together a union query that will bring me all the data I need at once, and then use some application logic on the result set to echo out the data correctly. Is this what you are hinting at with this statement: "But there are still ways of doing this that are better than running another query for each row returned."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to coerce the columns of the two full queries in such a way that it can all be returned in the UNION then you could join the union result to the comments and submissions tables.

```
SELECT records.datatype, comments.*, submissions.*
FROM (
    (
        SELECT comment_id, datatype
        FROM comments
        WHERE userid=3
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC
        LIMIT 20
    ) UNION ALL (
        SELECT content_id, datatype
        FROM submissions
        WHERE userid=3
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC
        LIMIT 20
    )
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 20
) AS records
LEFT JOIN comments
    ON records.comment_id = comments.comment_id
    AND records.datatype = 'comment'
LEFT JOIN submissions
    ON records.comment_id = submissions.content_id
    AND records.datatype = 'post'
```

Alternatively, you could run the two innermost selects with all required fields and then order the final result in PHP.

Comment: "Alternatively, you could run the two innermost selects with all required fields and then order the final result in PHP."

Comment: Whoops I didn't mean to submit the above comment yet. This is clever, I didn't know you could order a mysql result in php.

Comment: You could use the timestamps as the array keys and then sort the final array with krsort(). Give the above query a try. You still have not posted the full table structures. A single UNION will probably be the best approach depending on how much the table structures differ.

Comment: Does that "AS" command create a temporary table or something with the comment/submission ids as the id field and then join in the necessary data from the comment and submission tables? I'm confused why there is that additional records.datatype in the initial SELECT statement.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to add the table structures now, I was a bit worried I'd lose you since this will prob take me 10 minutes to grab it out of phpmyadmin and clean it up.

Comment: `AS` simply indicates an alias but it is creating a derived (temporary) table which exists during query execution only. I left `records.datatype` in the outer select so you know which fields to pull from the row. You will need to make sure that the fields selected from comments and submissions are named uniquely.

Comment: Okay I thought about what you said and I was able to "coerce" the columns of the two full queries into one successful union query. In order to do so, I had to pull in some data from other tables using an inner join in order to get some of the column data types to match, as well as have an equal number of columns selected in each of the queries but this is acceptable since everything is using indexes sufficiently to make the query execute pretty darn fast. Thanks for all your help.